# Format-independent binary object?

Tags: binary, compiler-construction, operating-system, llvm, system

Normally object files output by a compiler are in a specific format, e.g. ELF on Linux & etc., mach-O on macOS, and COFF/PE on Windows.

Now, assuming the source code is compatible across platforms. Is there a form of "object files" that are format-independent? In the sense that, an binary file of this "format-independent format" could be "converted" or "lowered" to real object files in whatever format (ELF/mach-O/..) later.

LLVM IR's binary form is a good example, as it could be lowered to machine code. However, LLVM IR is ISA-independent, so it is not "low-level" enough. Assuming ISA is given (e.g. x86_64), can I go even lower from ISA-independent to format-independent?

Comment: Please.. don't ask me "why do you want to do this", which is asked a lot here. I'm just curious. Yes, I know I might as well just recompile the source code, and yes, I know Java bytecode achieves similar goals (but it requires java VM at runtime) Thanks in advance!

Comment: Object code is mostly machine code for which various 'loose-ends' are fixed up at link time. There is no portable `object-code` and the effort to convert one form to another would be significant considering that object code has massive assumptions about the OS, external library, ABI and chip capabilities.  So answer to first question is "No". Thereby the answer to the second question is "No" as well.

Comment: Programs are target specific, a windows printf hello world program is not expected to produce the same program as a linux one.  Now at the object layer...maybe, but since the system calls and rules for that operating system in the construction of the binary are not in any way expected to be compatible, then have to ask what you are trying to do.   But as answered there are tools to do this, binutils has one built in.

Comment: The entire point of C and the illusion of compatible across platforms is because the binaries werent.  There is a layer below the source where compatibility stops.  Particularly with the same isa but different target operating system.s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that there is no such format, at least not one that the major compilers support.
(Even if there was such format, it would be practically useless without compiler support.)

But, with help of [`objconv` utility](https://github.com/gitGNU/objconv) which can convert between object-file formats, you can achieve what you described.
Simply choose one of the existing formats as the "independent" one and then use `objconv` to convert to "specific" formats (ELF/Mach-O/COFF).

It works pretty well, although some platform-specific data (like debugging information) are not preserved during conversion.